Zonal Statistics - Creation of a FeatureCollection to Perform Analysis on two dataset with different resolutions
I am am trying to create a FeatureCollection consisting of Squares in the GEE for performing an Analysis (Zonal Statistics) of two Raster Datasets with different resolutions.
I thought I could reduce (reducetoVector) the coarser dataset and then use the .map Funktion to .buffer and .bounds the points. Like this I would have a raster (Feature Collection) which can perform analysis on both datasets.
If I do so, I get buffers rectangulars which intersect (Picture: centroids in green and buffered "Squares" in lila). I assume that for this buffering (for buffering in general?) a projected CRS is needed.
Any suggestions?
Please see my code and below the code of my different tries.
//1.2.ERA-5 Land Daten 

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/DAILY_AGGR");
var mean = dataset.filterBounds(geometry)
                  .select('total_precipitation_sum')
                  .filterDate('2023-01-01', '2023-12-31')
                  .mean()
                  .multiply(10000)
                  .toInt();
                  
var projection = dataset.filterBounds(geometry).filterDate('2023-01-01', '2023-12-31').first().projection();
print(projection, 'Projection Precipitation Data');

var imageVisParam = {
  bands: ["total_precipitation_sum"],
  min: 10,
  max: 160,
  palette: ['#FFFFFF', '#00FFFF', '#0080FF', '#DA00FF', '#FFA400', '#FF0000']
};

print(mean, '1.2 Info mean ERA-5');
Map.addLayer(mean, imageVisParam, 'mean');
print(mean.projection().nominalScale().getInfo());

var coorsfeat = mean.reduceToVectors({
  reducer : null,
  geometry : geometry,
  scale:6800,
    geometryType : 'centroid',
  labelProperty : 'Precip',
  eightConnected: false
});
print(coorsfeat,{} ,'coorsfeat');

// // 1.3. Mosaic des Jahres 2023 hinzufügen 
//Map.addLayer(Precipitation23, precipitationVis, 'Total Precipitation 2023');  

var nominalScale = projection.nominalScale();
print('1.3 nominalScale ERA5', nominalScale);

//2. Raster generation
//2.1 Point generation -  make a coordinate image
// get coordinates image 
// put each lon lat in a list -> this time for getting an multipoint list 
function spacedPoints(AOI, projection) {
  // make a coordinate image
  // get coordinates image
  var latlon = ee.Image.pixelLonLat().reproject(projection);
  
// put each lon lat in a list -> this time for getting an multipoint list (more useful inside the GEE)

  var coords = latlon.select(['longitude', 'latitude'])
                 .reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(),
                                geometry: AOI,
                                scale: projection.nominalScale().toInt(),
                                maxPixels: 10e10
  });
  // zip the coordinates for representation. Example: zip([1, 3],[2, 4]) --> [[1, 2], [3,4]]

  var point_list = ee.List(coords.get('longitude')).zip(ee.List(coords.get('latitude')));
  // preset a random list
  var list = ee.List([0]);
  
// map over the point list and add features as geometry
    var feats = ee.FeatureCollection(point_list.map(function(point){
      var ind = point_list.indexOf(point);
      var feat = ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(point_list.get(ind)), {'ID': ind});
    return list.add(feat);
    }).flatten().removeAll([0]));

  return feats;
}

var output = spacedPoints(geometry, projection); 
print(output,{}, 'Centroides');
Map.addLayer(output, {color: 'green'},'Centroides');

//  2.2 Buffer points to squares
var buffer = output.map(function(f) {
  return f.buffer(5566).bounds(); 
});

print(buffer, {}, '2.2.2 Buffer Infos ');
Map.addLayer(buffer, {color: '800080'}, 'Buffer');

What I tried so far:

Points to Geometry, buffer geometries in EPSG: 3857, transform bufferd geometry to EPSG 4326 >> Result is one big polygone, as the .bounds command for multipoints result in one polgon

var ProFeat = output.map(function(f) {
  return f.transform('EPSG:3857', 0.001);
});

var buffer = ProFeat.map(function(f) {
  return f.buffer(5566).bounds(); 
});

var puffer = buffer.map(function(f){
  return f.transform ('EPSG:4326', 0.001);
});


Change CRS of the Points > as FeatureCollections don't have CRS, it is not possible

Points to Geometry (multipoints), transform multipoints to EPSG: 3857, if transforming the multipoints to a FeatureCollection it results in one polygon. Didn´t find a way for multipoints to points?


var points = output.geometry(); 
print (points);

var points3857 = points.transform('EPSG:3857', 0.001);

var buffer = points3857.buffer(5566).bounds();

var puffer = buffer.transform('EPSG:4326', 0.001);


Points to List, then it is possible to recreate the points/Feature Collection from the list, but there is no crs possibility at the list. So the newly created Feature Collection gets the default values.



If I understand correctly, you want to create a grid matching your coarse resolution image! In this case, what you are looking for is a built-in function .coveringGrid() that can create grid based on defined area, scale, and projection. See below
//create random geometry (your study area)
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Point(117.652, 27.41).buffer(50000).bounds()

// load your data
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/DAILY_AGGR").filterBounds(geometry)
                  .select('total_precipitation_sum')
                  .filterDate('2023-01-01', '2023-12-31');
var mean = dataset.mean().multiply(10000).toInt()
var imageVisParam = {bands: ["total_precipitation_sum"],min: 10,max: 160,palette: ['#FFFFFF', '#00FFFF', '#0080FF', '#DA00FF', '#FFA400', '#FF0000']};
Map.addLayer(mean, imageVisParam, 'mean',false);

// define  projection based on your data
var proj = dataset.first().projection()

// create grid
var grid = geometry.coveringGrid(proj).aside(print, 'the grid')

Map.addLayer(grid,{}, 'grid')
Map.centerObject(grid,10)


Yessss, thanks! It was exactly what i was looking for, thanks a lot :)
